# Generate charts with Google chart API

Tags: c#, android

i'am trying to generate a chart like this one: `http://chartpart.com/` but i don't know how to do that exactly.Do i need to make the string that generates the chart manually or do i need to send the data to a google  server and receive the string?(if so how do i send the data?)
PS:i would like to do all this in c# and send the resulting string via web service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apparently you need to generate the string yourself.I did just that and send the result to android via web service.

```
 [WebMethod]
        public ChartsClass GetChart(string UserId)
        {
            ChartsClass chart = new ChartsClass();
            DataSet1TableAdapters.WS_ChartIndicatorsTableAdapter adapter  =  new DataSet1TableAdapters.WS_ChartIndicatorsTableAdapter();
            DataSet1.WS_ChartIndicatorsDataTable table = adapter.GetChartIndicators(UserId);

            StringBuilder sbDescriptions = new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder sbValues = new StringBuilder();

            for(int i= 0 ;i< table.Rows.Count ;i++)
            {
                DataSet1.WS_ChartIndicatorsRow chartRow = (table.Rows[i] as DataSet1.WS_ChartIndicatorsRow);
                if (i > 0)
                {
                    sbDescriptions.Append("|");
                    sbValues.Append(",");
                }

                sbDescriptions.Append(chartRow.SectorId + " - " + chartRow.SectorDescription );
                sbValues.Append(chartRow.NetSaleValue.ToString());
            }

            chart.ChartString = String.Format("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=p3&chtt={0}&chd=t:{1}&chs=480x200&chl={2}&chco=ff0000,0000ff",
              "Live Sales", sbValues.ToString(), sbDescriptions.ToString());


            return chart;
        }
```

And in android you can load the result in a web view.

```
 chartView  = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.activity_chart_view);
 ChartsClass chart = new ChartsClass(soapObject);
 chartView.loadUrl(chart.chartStringSource);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to create a chart with user input, there's a wikiHow on that
 wikiHow Link: http://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-Google-Chart-with-User-Input

The graph this wikiHow creates is the same as the one on this website:
Website Link: http://www.quickcompromise.com/index.html